# Why Babel doesnt use javascript class when transpiling to ES2015?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I've recently been trying the online Babel transpiling tool, and I've noticed that when transpiling a class to ES2015, it doesnt use javascript class and creates `var _createClass = function () {...` boilerplate instead: [Demo](https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEDC0G8BQ1rAPYDsIBcBOArsDungBQCUi0OAFgJYQB0Y0AvNANoC60AvimhgAJsLIAPKghoNmYJgAcCEWhKoDUnAMoBPALYAjdCCb0cAUzxgSebpWp5zOAnkwzGLJgDcwIAuYh7AT4gA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=)

Yet, the javascript class keyword has been added in ES2015. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

The javascript class is used only when ticking ES2016.

Why is that?

Comment: that is the whole point of babel : generating code that can work on old browser

Comment: What exact settings did you choose?

Comment: @Bergi *Line wrap* and *es2015* only

Comment: @YoukouleleY As input format or output format? Can you post the permalink to your example?

Comment: @Bergi question edited

Comment: @AshKander I know that, but I thought we could target a specific version of ECMAScript and use all of the features it provides

Comment: @YoukouleleY Yup, you selected ES2015 as the *input* format. The output is given by the smart preset to run in older browsers - that's why it transpiles to ES5.

Comment: @Bergi OK, but then why when I tick *es2016* the code remains unchanged, shouldn't it output as ES5 too ?

Comment: @YoukouleleY Ooops, I was wrong, you weren't using a smart environment preset. The [ES2015 preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-es2015) transpiles everything that's new in ES2015 to the previous syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've noticed that when transpiling a class to ES2015, it doesnt use javascript class: [https://babeljs.io/repl#?presets=es2015&…](https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEDC0G8BQ1rAPYDsIBcBOArsDungBQCUi0OAFgJYQB0Y0AvNANoC60AvimhgAJsLIAPKghoNmYJgAcCEWhKoDUnAMoBPALYAjdCCb0cAUzxgSebpWp5zOAnkwzGLJgDcwIAuYh7AT4gA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=)

You weren't transpiling to ES2015, you were transpiling *from* ES2015 to an older version. The [ES2015 preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-es2015) selects all the transformations that generate ES3/5 code for ES2015 stuff.

> The javascript class is used only when ticking ES2016.

Yes, it keeps the `class` syntax and other features from ES2015 when you only transpile the ES2016 (or higher) stuff.

Answer (score 0):

> Yet, the javascript class keyword has been added in ES2015

Yes, the keyword was defined on ES2015 and `class` was already a reserved word before that, but the actual implementation is a different story. As @AshKander mentions in they comment, the point of using babel with a specific target is to get that code to work on all browsers that support such target.

[List of reserved keywords (present and future)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords)